# Java returning entered text

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My first post here on stackoverflow.
The task is:
Write a method that shall return a String, the method has no parameters. The method is going to read some word from the keyboard. The inputs ends with the word "END" the method should return this whole text as a long row:

```
"HI" "HELLO" "HOW" "END"
```

Make is so that the method return the string

```
HIHELLOHOW
```

MY CODE IS:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Upg13_IS_IT_tenta {
    String x, y, c, v;
    public String text(){
        System.out.println("Enter your first letter");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //Can you even make this outside main?
        x = sc.next();
        y = sc.next();
        c = sc.next();
        v = sc.next(); // Here I assign every word with a variable which i later will return. (at the             bottom //i write return x + y + c;). This is so that i get the string "HIHELLOWHOW"

        sc.next();
        sc.next();
        sc.next();
        sc.next(); // Here I want to return all the input text as a long row

        return x + y + c;
    }   
}
```

---

I know that my code has a lot of errors in it, I am new to Java so I would like so help and explaining of what I've done wrong. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
     public String text(){

        InputStreamReader iReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(iReader);

        String line = "";
        String outputString = "";
        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            outputString += line;
        }

      return outputString;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want something like

```
public String text() {
    String input;
    String output = "";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    input = sc.next();
    while (! input.equals("END")) {
        output = output + input;
        input = sc.next();
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have done now is build a program that can only handle one specific input.
You might want to aim for something more reusable:

```
public String text(){
        System.out.println("Talk to me:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        while(!text.toString().endsWith("END"))
        {
            text.append(sc.next());
        }

        return text.toString().substring(0, text.toString().length()-3);
    }
```

This builds a single *String* out of your input, stops when the String ends with "END" and returns the String without the last 3 letters ("END").